# InnoDB CURRENT_TIMESTAMP update without updating row data

Tags: mysql, innodb

Is there a simple way of triggering the update of a "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" column without actually updating data in the row?

Comment: I suspect not, but why would you want to do this?

Comment: Or are you seeing spurious timestamp changes, and wondering how they're happening?

Comment: I'm using the current timestamp for a different purpose than usually intended for. I'm trying to use a hash of it a part of a russian doll cache system key. Therefore, when an update occurs the key gets automatically invalidated but sometimes I might want to trigger that "invalidation" (key regeneration) manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply update the timestamp directly:

```
UPDATE yourTable SET timestamp_column = NOW()
```